# Google Workspace with Outlook: set up multiple Gmail accounts to single Google Workspace mail profile

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, gmail, google-workspace, google-sync

My client has a single Gmail account set up in Microsoft Outlook 365 on Windows 10 with Google Workspace Sync for Microsoft Outlook aka. [GWSMO](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/gssmo/) (formerly known as G Suite Sync for Microsoft Outlook, GSSMO).

They now need to set up a second Gmail account to **the same** Google Workspace mail profile in **Control Panel > Mail > Profiles**. How do I add the second Gmail account given the current setup?

There seems to be no option for this under **Applications > Google Workspace Sync** and there seems to be very little or no documentation on this. Can anyone help? Thx.

Comment: Is the second Gmail account also with GSSMO? If it's a normal gmail account, we should be able to add it directly in an exsting outlook profile. If not, for the Gmail account with GSSMO, I also haven't found any information about it, considering the profile may be created automatically when you configure GSSMO, I think it may be difficult to change it in the point of Outlook.

Comment: @Jade Yes, the second account is also supposed to be with GWSMO and a dedicated GWSMO profile is indeed automatically created in **Control Panel > Mail > Profiles** when you do the initial configuration. However, I know it's possible to add a second GWSMO account to the same profile - I've seen it work on somebody else's pc - I just don't know how it's done.

Comment: Okay, hope others who has similar operations could share his experience here. By the way, configuring multiple accounts in an Outlook profile may cause some issue(such as send from incorrect address or corrupted profile etc.), so in my opnion, we would better to configure different accounts in different outlook profiles.

Comment: Well, yes and no to your last point. Yes because of the reasons you gave, but no because it's very impractical having to switch profiles when you work. And yes, hopefully sombody out there share their experience.

Comment: Maybe you could also try to post your issue in any related GWSMO forum, there may also be some users who know more related information about it.

Comment: @Jade Yes, it's a good idea, maybe some Google support forum. I get the feeling though, that MS and Google aren't exactly keen on posting information about this as they're competitors and want people to stick with respective systems. Anyway, the solution for the client was to only use GWSMO (with exchange) for the primary mail account and then IMAP (with only mail synchronization) for the secondary as it turned this was sufficient. This setup works flawlessly, but is not optimal as Outlook works differently with different mail protocols, so I'm still interested if anyone can answer my question

Comment: "By the way, configuring multiple accounts in an Outlook profile may cause some issue(such as send from incorrect address or corrupted profile etc.),"  Very very incorrect.  this is standard practice .  Please do not post this type of tripe.

Comment: @TomG11 You're absolutely right that it's standard practice to have multiple mail accounts associated with a single profile. However, it's also true that this can cause mails to be sent from the wrong mail account if you forget to switch to the right account before you send. This is purely human error and has nothing to do with the robustness of the setup, which presumably was your point (but maybe not Jade's). Regarding corruption, I do agree with you, as you can separate the .pst files for each mail account, i.e. there's no difference in this regard compared to non-GWSMO setups.

Comment: 2023 solution on Windows 11 is Start > All apps > Google Sync (it's a folder) > Add account for delegation [or] Setup a Google Workspace Sync user. I don't have enough reputation to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you found your answer but I did this and it worked.

Google Workspace Migration for Microsoft® Outlook®
https://tools.google.com/dlpage/gsmmo/#

Make sure and open your primary account and migrate your other to it.

Comment: Yes, that is the standard way of setting up a GWSMO account in Outlook for Windows, but I don't think there's any option to migrate **several** GWSMO accounts to the **same** profile with this tool, unless you want to merge accounts into one, which most clients don't. The goal is to have several GWSMO accounts (with exchange of mails/calendars/contacts) set up to a single mail profile whilst keeping each mailbox separate and I don't think that is currently possible with this tool, unless they've changed it since I posted back in March 2021.

Comment: From the [documentation](https://support.google.com/a/answer/176213): "You can set up Google Workspace Migration for Microsoft Outlook (GWMMO) for users in your organization so they can import email, calendar, or contact data from a Microsoft Exchange account or PST file.". In my case, the client wanted to set up a Gmail account in Outlook with exchange, rather than import data from Microsoft Exchange or a PST file.